# Old style seekbar in new android versions

Tags: android, android-seekbar

### Type-1

[image]

### Type-2

[image]

```
<SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/SeekBarTestPlay"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

---

### Description:

**What i know**

- I am aware that android uses  `Type-1` style for lower sdk and
  `type-2` style for higher sdk

**What i am trying to do**

- I am trying to use `type-1` style in lower and higher sdk's also

### {EDIT}

```
<SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/SeekBarTestPlay"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gingerbread widget styles can be applied using the appropriate `@android:style/Widget` style.

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/SeekBarTestPlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/Widget.SeekBar" />
```

If you want to force all `SeekBar`s in your app to look like Gingerbread seek bars, you can set the `android:seekBarStyle` attribute in your theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" ...>
    <item name="android:seekBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.SeekBar</item>
</style>
```

If you want your entire app to look like Gingerbread, you can set your app theme to extend the base Theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an `android:theme` attribute for your `SeekBar` with a style that will be shown across all API levels that support it. The theme you want for your type-1 is called *Theme*.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme"
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know of this attribute [+1] ..... what is the name of the `Type1` ... theme ..... when i use the code in edit it didn't show any changes ?

Comment: The name of type-1 theme is called `Theme`. Type-2 is `Theme.Holo`.

Comment: I tried this way but i couldnt change the style  .... but defining style in style .xml specified by another answer by `alanv` resolved it